# Junk characters while debbuging in keil

Tags: c, linked-list, stm32, keil

I'm working with linked list in keil, I have 3 structs which are :

```
typedef struct CanSnifferTrame Trame ;
struct CanSnifferTrame{
  uint32_t id;
  uint32_t lastTime;
  uint8_t prevData[8];
  uint8_t lastData[8];
  uint32_t freq[8];
  uint32_t lastfreq[8];
  uint32_t intervalle[8];
  uint8_t changing;
  uint8_t count ;
  Trame *next ;

};
typedef struct Tete Sniffer ;
struct Tete {
    Trame *first;
};
typedef struct Result Result ;
struct Result{
  uint8_t snifferC;
  Sniffer *tete;
};
```

I try just to initialize the list

```
Result *ResultVar = malloc(sizeof(ResultVar));
ResultVar->snifferC = 0 ;
ResultVar->tete = malloc(sizeof(Sniffer));
ResultVar->tete->first = NULL;
```

While debugging, `ResultVar->tete->first` is `NULL`, but the list is not empty, it has infinity of elements (`id`, `lasttime`, `freq`, ...) with junk characters.

Comment: Need to post code that demonstrates "list is not empty, it has infinity of elements" ... and what "list" you refer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `malloc(sizeof(*ResultVar))` or `malloc(sizeof(Result))` instead of `malloc(sizeof(ResultVar))`.

Comment: The list is not empty and junk characters are always there..